# Trying to change the profile of logged in user through apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

My requirement is when a user logged into customer portal using credentials-profile has to be changed when a action is called on button-click.
At the time of login -profile is say 'abc'.
I have called a future method onclick of a button to change the profile to say 'xyz'.
I am able to change the useremail but not the profileID,it is showing the following error:
**FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot change profile for current user: Profile ID**

My future method is as follows:

`@future
  public static void updateuserAFL(id userId,id profileid){
  User tempUser = [select id,name,Email,Username,Profileid from user where id=:userId ];
  tempUser.ProfileId=profileid; 
  tempUser.Email='test@mphasis.com';
  update tempUser;
  }`

Can anyone please help me how to change the profie of the logged in user..

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look once on below link to update user profile using apex code.

[update user profile through apex](http://salesforce-tweaks.blogspot.in/2016/02/how-to-changeupdate-profile-of-user-in.html)

Here we are doing a HttpCallout, which in result update user profile as admin mode.

```
public void callPublicSite(){

     String remoteURL = 'https://testing.force.com/ProfileUpdate?userId=' userId+'&profileId='+profileIdToUpdate;

     HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
     httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
     httpRequest.setEndpoint(remoteURL);
     HttpResponse httpResponse = new Http().send(httpRequest);

}
```

//page name: ProfileUpdate

```
public void doProfileUpdate()
{     
   try
   {
      String userId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userId');
      String profileId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('profileId');
      update new User(Id=userId,ProfileId = profileId);
   }
   Catch(Exception e)
   {
     System.debug('::::user profile not update'+e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Same type of question is asked in salesforce QA 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090mLIAQ
The above link might help.

Comment: Shanker, could you please provide more information in your answer than to refer to another site ?  At least a summary of the answer there is prefered, so that the answer and content is not dependant on data elsewhere.

Comment: Found a nice video on youtube which demonstrate a workaround for the problem.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2fJWeJscps
I will update my answer with details solution to the problem after i get back to home